# Inconsistency with WeatherData

Tags: curated-data

1. 

```
Normal[WeatherData[
                WeatherData[
                 Entity["City", {"Birmingham", "Alabama", "UnitedStates"}]], 
                "MeanTemperature", {{2019, 1, 1}, {2020, 12, 31}, "Day"}]][[All, 
               2]] // Length
```

Gives 730 which makes sense because `DateObject[{2020, 12, 31}] - DateObject[{2019, 1, 1}]`=`730`

but

2.

```
Normal[WeatherData[
    WeatherData[
     Entity["City", {"Huntsville", "Alabama", "UnitedStates"}]], 
    "MeanTemperature", {{2019, 1, 1}, {2020, 12, 31}, "Day"}]][[All, 
   2]] // Length
```

Gives 731, why?

3.

```
 Normal[WeatherData[
    WeatherData[
     Entity["City", {"Auburn", "Alabama", "UnitedStates"}]], 
    "MeanTemperature", {{2019, 1, 1}, {2020, 12, 31}, "Day"}]][[All, 
   2]] // Length
```

Gives 681, why?

4.

```
Normal[WeatherData[
    Entity["City", {"Auburn", "Alabama", "UnitedStates"}], 
    "MeanTemperature", {{2019, 1, 1}, {2020, 12, 31}, "Day"}]][[All, 
   2]] // Length
```

Gives `731`, why?

Is there a way to get consistent data i.e. `730` temperature data for each city in the US?

Comment: `WeatherData` often has missing data. I showed how to identify what days are missing in [this](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2169182) post on the Wolfram Community site.

Comment: Thanks @RohitNamjoshi your approach will certainly come in handy.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi is there a way to just get a list of missing dates rather than date intervals?

Comment: You might use `Complement[DateRange[{2019, 1, 1}, {2020, 12, 31}], DateList /@ 
  WeatherData[Entity["WeatherStation", "KAUO"], "MeanTemperature", {{2019, 1, 1}, {2020, 12, 31}, "Day"}]["Dates"]]` to get a list of missing dates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The results given by [`WeatherData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeatherData.html) are not inconsistent. `WeatherData` gives different results for different location specifications, and that is what's happening in your examples. Additionally, individual weather stations may not have data for every date.

Here's how `WeatherData` works for different location specifications:

- When the location in `WeatherData[loc, ...]` is a weather station identifier, the result is the data for the weather station.
- When the location is a city, given as `WeatherData[loc]`, the result is the *nearest weather station* to the city for which data has ever been available.
- When the location is a city, given as `WeatherData[loc, ...]`, the result is data for the *nearest high-reliability weather station*.

This means that if you want the "best" data for a city, use the city as the location, not the nearest weather station.

**Why are there different numbers of data samples?**

Let's use Auburn as an example. When the location is a city, `WeatherData[city]` gives the *nearest station*, but `WeatherData[city, ...]` returns data for the *nearest high-relability station*. For example,

```
city = Entity["City", {"Auburn", "Alabama", "UnitedStates"}];
nearestStation = WeatherData[city];
```

This gives the nearest weather station to Auburn, which (currently) is KAUO, and `WeatherData` for the station is:

```
WeatherData[nearestStation, "MeanTemperature", {{2019, 1, 1}, {2020, 12, 31}, "Day"}]["PathLength"]
```

which shows that station KAUO has 681 temperature samples for the dates. Instead, when the location is a city, `WeatherData` returns data for the *nearest high-relability station*.

```
WeatherData[city, "MeanTemperature", {{2019, 1, 1}, {2020, 12, 31}, "Day"}]["PathLength"]
```

which shows that the nearest high-reliability station has 731 temperature samples.

Comment: Thanks @creidhne for clearly explaining it. Even though there are 730 days with that time span, why am I getting 731 data points? For the kind of data set that I am trying to create, I would like to have exactly the same number of data points for all the cities. So, are there ways to do so?

Comment: @psimeson Ah, yes, but `Today - Yesterday` is 1 day, yet there are two samples, one for today, and one for yesterday, which shows that there is 1 more sample than the difference in the dates. `WeatherData` returns a `TimeSeries`. When there are missing date samples, you can interpolate values for the missing dates with `ts = TimeSeries[WeatherData[...], TemporalRegularity -> True]`.

Comment: @psimeson I'll update the answer with some extra examples, but to get the full range of dates, you need `ts[dates]` where `dates` is a range from a start date to an end date. See the *Basic Uses* section of [`TimeSeries`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeries.html) for more methods, e.g., `TimeSeriesRescale`, `TimeSeriesInsert`, etc.

Comment: thanks again. That would be helpful. I am also looking more into it. I have about 1250 US cities and for most of them I get 731 but there are a few where I get <731. I am trying to fix that. I looked to `TimeSeriesResample` with interval 1 but Mathematica crashed.

Comment: `city = Entity["City", {"Auburn", "Alabama", "UnitedStates"}];
nearestStation = WeatherData[city];`
`ts = TimeSeries[
   WeatherData[nearestStation, 
    "MeanTemperature", {{2019, 1, 1}, {2020, 12, 31}, "Day"}], 
   TemporalRegularity -> True];`
`md1 = Complement[DateRange[{2019, 1, 1}, {2020, 12, 31}], 
   DateList /@ td["Dates"]];`
`nl1 = Table[{md1[[i]], ts[md1[[i]]]}, {i, Length[md1]}]`
`nll1 = TimeSeriesInsert[ts, nl1];`
`Intersection[Normal[nll1][[All, 2]][[All, 1]], 
  Normal[td][[All, 2]][[All, 1]]] // 
 Length` -- > Should be 681 but it' s 362

Comment: `Intersection[Normal[nll1][[All, 2]][[All, 1]], Normal[td][[All, 2]][[All, 1]]] //   Length` should be `Intersection[Normal[nll1][[All, 2]][[All, 1]], Normal[ts][[All, 2]][[All, 1]]] //   Length`

Comment: Sorry, as soon as I consider the list as a set, I get rid of non-unique elements when doing set operations, right? `Intersection[{1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5}, {3, 3, 4}] --> {3,4}`that will screw up my calculation. If I do complement `Complement[Normal[nll1][[All, 2]][[All, 1]], 
  Normal[ts][[All, 2]][[All, 1]]] // Length` then I get 50 which is the 50 new elements that I had to add.

Comment: it seems like it's almost impossible to get clean data. I have to interpolate and extrapolate. And the interpolation and especially exploration fails.